# Ubuntu Terminal showing bash: /home/vostro/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory on Launch

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, installation

In Ubuntu, whenever I launch terminal, on top Terminal shows a message

```sh
bash: /home/vostro/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

after that I can enter commands, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file for any startup scripts that may have gotten added by RVM and you probably need to remove or comment out those lines.

Comment: Please guide me to find this file, I don't know where is it situated, I've searched internet, it is not there in ~/ Directory.

Comment: what about ~/.profile but perhaps you're using a non-bash shell.  what is the output of `echo "$SHELL"` ?

Comment: I am getting /bin/bash as output.

Comment: what about if you do `which rvm` ?  It seems like something was uninstalled incorrectly.  To fully remove RVM you can run `rvm implode` and also maybe [have a look here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/35e894c7070eaabc38d91220f6e26d1585a7098a/scripts/functions/implode) to see what that does